# Button position in optiontransferselect tag

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am trying to relocate the button position in `optiontransferselect` tag.

When I run the program, I notice the `addToRightLabel="-> move to the right side"` button is under `addToLeftLabel="<- move to the left side"` button.

So I try to make the `addToLeftLabel="<- move to the left side"` button below the `addToRightLabel="-> move to the right side"` button.

Here is the code in the jsp.

```
<s:optiontransferselect 
allowUpDownOnLeft="false"
allowUpDownOnRight="false"
allowSelectAll="false"
allowAddAllToLeft="false"
allowAddAllToRight="false"

addToRightLabel="-> move to the right side"
addToLeftLabel="<- move to the left side"

leftTitle="Option values:"
headerKey="0"
name="option"
list= "optionList"
doubleId="selectedValues"
doubleHeaderKey="0"
rightTitle="Selected Values:"
doubleList="selectedOptionList" doubleName="selectOption">
</s:optiontransferselect>
```

In the code, I notice `addToLeftLabel="<- move to the left side"` is already under `addToRightLabel="-> move to the right side"` , however when I run the program, the `addToRightLabel="-> move to the right side"` still below the  `addToLeftLabel="<- move to the left side"`

I visit this two websites [Struts 2 optiontransferselect example](https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-optiontransferselect-example/) and [optiontransferselect](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/optiontransferselect-tag.html) but I don't get the idea to solve the problem.

Although in worst case, I think I can swap values between `list= "optionList"` and `doubleList="selectedOptionList"`, I am seeking a better solution on how to relocate the button position.

Therefore, my question is how to relocate the button position in `optiontransferselect` tag (put `addToLeftLabel="<- move to the left side"` under `addToRightLabel="-> move to the right side"`).

Thanks.

Comment: The tag is rendered via freemarker, you can change the code to suit you needs.

Answer (score 0):

I notice I am using struts2-core jar, so I open it in Eclipse, go to template.simple and then find optiontransferselect.ftl. Once open the file, just swap the position for `<#if parameters.allowAddToRight?default(true)><#t/>` and `<#if parameters.allowAddToLeft?default(true)><#t/>`.

Although this is not a good solution, this solves the problem.

The better practice is to create a new ftl file for optiontransferselect and then write code to suit my case, this action is to prevent the new struts2-core jar update overwrite the modified code.